# When to request a "delayed" start date

Tags: interviewing, start-date

I have been recruited by another company and requested to come in for an interview. I am considering going in for the interview however I have no intention of leaving my current job for at least 3 months due to Bonus payouts.

Should I mention this fact prior to coming in for an interview or wait until they actually offer me a position.

Comment: One reason to mention this to the recruiter: everyone wants money, they know this. They would rather hire a happy employee, sometimes they will even provide you a signing bonus if they cant wait. No one wants to miss out on a bonus and they might be understanding of that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the interview process doesn't put your current job or bonus at risk and you are genuinely interested in this new position, you should proceed.

This is a point of negotiation when you are trying to reach terms of employment. While it is very unusual in the US for a 3 month delay in start date, it is not unusual in other places. Also, some companies have broader concerns or needs than "immediate start date" although often they want a start date that is as soon as possible.

You might find that, after the interview, you are not interested or they are not interested. Alternatively, you may find out that the opportunity is worth giving up your bonus. You seem pretty resolute on staying until you receive it. However, consider that it's also possible that your new employer is very eager to fill the position and could offer a "signing bonus" or something else to either offset or fully cover your expected bonus.

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard of a company delaying the start date by 3 months - if they're hiring it's because they need to fill a position ***now***.

The only possible exception has been in the case of students who are still in school.

It's completely unreasonable for you to ask, and I don't think you will get the job if you do mention it.

Comment: In the UK, 3 months isn't an unheard of notice period for senior staff - but it's certainly something you'd mention on your CV so companies were aware of it.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - very interesting. Glad you mentioned it, as I would never have imagined that sort of timeline being acceptable. I guess you learn something new every day. Cheers!

Comment: In France, it's even standard, as once you send your leave request, you're expected to work still 3 months there. That's one of the reasons consulting has high proportions here. Consultants are usually available now.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z - again, very interesting. In Canada I have not heard of this kind of leniency. Typically they want you to start ASAP.

Comment: That is not correct.  An oil company has a budget to add 5 geologist.   Microsoft needs to add 12 testers.   Hospital has budget to add 10 nurses.   An open position is not always an immediate need.

Comment: The op doesnt need 3 months notice, the OP does not want to leave for 3 months because of impending bonuses.

Comment: @Frisbee - I can't add every possible scenario. Typically when a company goes through the trouble of interviewing it's because they need someone there to fill a position.

Comment: I once knew someone in the UK who was on a 1 month notice per year of service up to max 12 months notice due to the specific knowledge he had.  But it cuts both ways, they had to give him the same.

Comment: No kidding they hire to fill a position.  You asserted  "if they're hiring it's because they need to fill a position **now**".

Comment: Twice I've had delayed start dates *exceed* 3 months. I don't think there's necessarily a norm here. All depends on the situation.

Comment: The need to hire now is typical of low skill jobs. But for ones that require specific experience/education a smart employer will wait for the right employee. I live in Canada and recently did exactly what the OP is asking about. I dont see any harm in asking the recruiter if its possible (after recieving an offer)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the time sensitivity of filling the open position and how bad they want you.

If the are looking fill an empty position on a manufacturing floor then they pretty much need it filled now.

If is an analyst doing strategic planning then wait a few months for the right person they want is not a big deal.

If they got budget to fill or add 10 slots for the same position then spreading is no big deal.

I would tell them straight up you are waiting on a bonus.  I know people that have had their bonus bought out to come on board now.

If they recruited you then they want you.  I don't think you need to tell them prior to coming to the interview.  But in that interview if it feels like they might give you an offer and you might want to accept the offer then you should tell them.  For sure tell them before it get to them extending a verbal offer.

Answer (score 1):

I would wait until the offer, otherwise why complicate things for no good reason.

However, you can ask in the interview what timeframe they have in mind for bringing someone on board, in terms of the length of the selection process and start.

You can usually negotiate a start date within 2-4 weeks from the time of offer.

Assuming the recruitment process lasts a couple months, this puts you pretty close to your 3+ months preferred timeframe.

If they ask you back when you are ready to start, don't tell about the 3 month constraint. The idea is not to make your timing constraint become a point of contention and provide reason for doubt on their end.

Rather, say that you have some ongoing projects you would need to wrap up but generally do not anticipate any delays or issues with starting within the expected timeframe.  Don't give the impression that you are struggling with this point - just give a simple concise answer and move on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The time to bring up start dates is after there's a mutual agreement on you being the candidate they'd like to hire. At the point, that's just part of the whole on-boarding negotiation process (start date, salary, benefits, etc.)